# WordPress edit section not working properly

Tags: wordpress

This block encountered an error and can not be previewed.
After getting the update from WordPress it happens. I have updated the PHP version from the server too.
After the update message of “Howdy! Your site at [https://gossipfunda.com](https://gossipfunda.com/) has been updated automatically to WordPress 5.4.”
We got errors “This block encountered an error and can not be previewed ” in draft articles as well as for new posts.
Here I am Providing the Screenshot of the problem
https://gossipfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Capture.png

Comment: This question appears to be about a Wordpress configuration issue and less so about writing code or software development. 

You might have better luck at the Wordpress support forums.https://wordpress.org/support/

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache ([instructions](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)), if that doesn't work then try removing that particular block and add again (by removing block you will have to write content again)